# What the best solution to display the detail row with asp control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to display data and detail.
When I click on one data (= one row), it has to display details of this data.

With DevExpress, there is DetailRow

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ...>
  ...
  <Templates>
     <DetailRow>
        <dx:ASPxGridView>
              ... 
        <dx:ASPxGridView/>
     <DetailRow>
   <Templates>
<dx:ASPxGridView/>
```

But I don't use DevExpress and I search a solution with Asp Control.

I saw this [post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160773/Expandable-Rows-in-GridView#xx4512426xx) but I want to know if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this very nice Master-Detail example with the GridView, DetailsView and ModalPopup Controls

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/04/masterdetail_with_the_gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

BootStrap is your friend!

you can use modal window to achieve this. Or many more things that it has to offer.
Just browse the documentation and pick something you like.

http://getbootstrap.com/

it's a css/javascript library full of stuff to help you with your web interfaces.

this way, you don't have to use asp controls!

You might also want to look up Jquery for handling events on your page.